# Should we take off our [footwear]?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags

A short time ago, [a blatantly off-topic question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/114161/which-food-market-should-i-visit-in-pennsylvania) got posted on main and swiftly deleted, and I was curious to see that it had been (incorrectly) tagged [footwear](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/footwear). I didn't know we had such a tag. It seems as though [only one other question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/96162/how-might-digitigrade-biped-shoes-work) has used it, about 8 months ago, and that it was created specifically for that question.

I don't think we need this tag. Should we get rid of it?

Comment: While your post is self-explanatory, it wouldn't hurt to add a link to "blatantly off-topic question". Some of us like to look at the question in question.

Comment: @a4android It's been deleted now, but I have a link to it in my Inbox, so I'll add that in.

Comment: Thanks for the link Wow! One very weird question considering our site. Most definitely it came to the wrong place.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This feels pretty synonymous with [clothing](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothing).  I'd vote for merging the tag or just deleting it altogether.

Comment: Makes sense to me. I say delete the tag, and then add the [tag:clothing] tag onto that other question.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as calling it synonymous; [tag:footwear] is clearly a subset of [tag:clothing]. But that's okay; sometimes tags turn out to be *too* specific.